# How to create 32bit or 64bit only installer with Installshield 2010?

Tags: installation, installshield, installscript

I mean doing this in a InstallScript project so the installer would exit in the first place if it's not running with correct processor type.

I found it'll be easy if it's a InstallScript MSI project, just modify the "Template summary" field, while this options is not there in InstallScript project.

I have some requirements which could be met perfectly by InstallScript project type so I cannot git it up.

Thank U in advance for your advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In InstallScript you often have to roll your own behavior. In this case, it's easy: just check the [SYSINFO struct](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/robo/projects/installshield16langref/langrefsysinfo.htm) for the parameters you require, and provide appropriate messaging and abort (or continue). In this case it's probably `SYSINFO.bIsWow64`.